# How to find the maximum no of digits in the list in python

Tags: python

For example 
If the list contains numbers  3 , 14 , 24 , 6 , 157 , 132 ,12
It should give the maximum no of digits as 3

Comment: First, write an algorithm that finds the number of digits of a number. Then, use that algorithm on each item in the list, storing the largest result. Hope this helps.

Comment: If i use another empty list and stores the no of digits and then sort to get the maximum no of digits .It will make it lengthy so i am asking for any other way to do so.

Comment: Hint: you don't need to sort a list to find its maximum value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case your list contains negative numbers you could pass generator expression calling [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#abs) as an argument for [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> mylist = [3, 14, 24, 6, 157, 132, 12, -100]
>>> len(str(max(abs(x) for x in mylist)))
3
```

Note that above only works with integers. If your list contains other types of numbers, like `float` or [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) then changes are required.

Comment: Interesting (and significant) if the OP does or does not want a minus-sign to count as "a digit."

Comment: @MikeRobinson By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit) minus-sign is not a digit but then on the other hand only OP knows what he's looking for.

Comment: Bingo ... as I said in my Answer, the "right" answer to this problem depends *entirely* on what the OP is looking for, and for how-thoroughly s/he has thought through the various subtle implications and interpretations of the problem. The more you think about it, the more you find to ask: "Do you mean this? Or that? Or ...?"

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
mylist = [3, 14, 24, 6, 157, 132, 12]
print (len(str(max([abs(element) for element in mylist]))))
#3
#This will work for negative numbers too
```

Comment: You've edited your answer to be the same as another answer without giving attribution

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I have seen the answer of niemmi  after editing mine.

Answer (score 2):

The first requirement is to decide *exactly* what **you** mean by "number of digits."  For example, `-2.1352` contains ... how many digits?  One? Five? Six? Seven? An argument could be made in favor of each of these.

Then, in the case of *floating point* numbers, there's the question of rounding. Float-binary is base-*two* which must be converted to base-*ten* at some number of digits' (decimal) precision. Is that number *fixed?* Would `-2.3` (two digits? one? three?) be displayed as `-2.3000` hence five digits (four? six?).

A "code golf" exercise like this can be tackled in any number of ways. Step-one is to hammer out exactly what you *mean* in your statement of the problem to be coded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
max = list[0]
for i in range(1,len(list)):
    if len(list[i]) > max:
        max = len(list[i])
```

Comment: You probably don't mean `max = list[0]` if max is supposed to be the length

Comment: I suspect `len(list[i])` will fail, because numbers don't have a length.

Answer (score 1):

```
tempMaxDig = 0
for item in numList:
    num = len(str(item))
    if num > tempMaxDig:
         tempMaxDig =  num 


return tempMaxDig
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
len(str(max(list)))
```

what we are doing here finding the maximum number, then lenght of that.

Answer (score 1):

"Try this

```
mylist = [3, 14, 24, 6, 157, 132, 12]
print (len(str(max(mylist)))
```

"

Sorry I would comment but < 50 rep. Credit to @soumendra

Soumendra's solution works but not for negative numbers. Easy way to do this is:

```
mylist = [3, 14, 24, 6, 157, 132, 12]
a = len(str(max(mylist)))
b = len(str(min(mylist)))
print max([a, b])
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to treat the elements as strings so you can ask for their length or number of digits.

Some code

```
#Your list
L = [ 3 , 14 , 24 , 6 , 157 , 132 ,12]

# Imperative
max_digits = 0
for element in L:
    n_digits = len(str(element))
    if n_digits > max_digits:
        max_digits = n_digits

# Funtional
max_digits = reduce(lambda x,y: x if x>y else y, map(lambda x: len(str(x)), L), 0)
```